# Port forwarding, gateway timeout

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, webserver

I want to connect my web server to internet. I have set DHCP reservation (basically, set static IP) to server (192.168.1.100) and forwarded port 80 on router. If I want access my web page from internal network my web page is available. But if I tell public IP to my friend he get **gateway timeout**.

**Router configurations:**

[image: router configuration]

**Network schema:**

[image: network schema]

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: There a reason you have the port field blank??  You are giving your friend the `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` address right instead of the `192.168.1.100`.  Be sure you setup a DMZ to the router on the modem (192.168.1.1).

Comment: On the left side I selected HTTP, this are pre-defined rules.

Comment: ISPs are notorious for disabling this type of thing.  If you are going to do it, you need to do it, on a port that isn't on port 80.  Try setting up the port 80 rule manually.  LinkSYS is notorious for having buggy firmware.

Comment: If I use `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` address I see my webpage, if my friend use it he get gateway timeout (he is not inside of my private network). I think it is something with modem or maybe ISP blocking port forwarding?

Comment: An ISP cannot block you forwarding traffic from within your own network.  They can stop traffic from comming into your network though.

Comment: See EDIT, I have changed configuration, but still same problem.

Comment: First you should test if the port is open (I use [ShieldsUp](https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?bh0bkyd2)). If it is open then because you see your webpage from inside the network (even if using the public IP this will not come from outside the router!) and your friend does not, I would check the firewall on the web server. If it is on a Windows machine you should check the firewall if it allows domain, private and public access. For testing you can shortly disable the firewall to see if this is the problem. You could test with wireshark to see if the requests are getting through from your router.